# Can radius be configured to assign ip addresses?

Tags: networking, radius, freeradius

I would need to know if a radius server can be configured in such a way that it allows to assign a specific ip address to a device when it connects.
I mean, when a mobile device connects to the wifi network issued by an access point and authenticates through raidus, once that authentication has been successful, give the device a specific ip.

If it is possible, how can I make this configuration? by using a pool of ips?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Generally not unless your wireless access point or wireless lan controller runs a local DHCP server where it pre-populates lease information from Access-Accept packets.

If your WAP/WLC does support this you'll be able to assign addresses by adding the `Framed-IP-Address` and/or `Framed-IPv6-Address` attributes to an Access-Accept.

The sqlippool module in FreeRADIUS v3 will be able to do assignments from a pool.

Just to mention... FreeRADIUS v3 supports DHCPv4 natively, and FreeRADIUS v4 supports DHCPv4 and DHCPv6.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP bind MAC address might help. You can bind a specific MAC address of your device to a specific IP address.